# Getting or Simulating GL_PACK_ROW_LENGTH and GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH in iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0

It seems that using `glPixelStorei` with `GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH` and `GL_PACK_ROW_LENGTH` is not supported on iOS.

Is is possible to somehow simulate them to get the same effect for memory stride when using `glTexImage2D` and `glReadPixels` respectively (without an extra prior copy to aligned memory)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a pretty solution, but you could read/write the data row by row.

For the `glTexImage2D()` case, you would call `glTexImage2D()` once with the full size, and with NULL for the last argument. Then use a separate `glTexSubImage2D()` call for each row.

Same idea for `glReadPixels()`. You can use a call per row, and apply the correct row length to the pointer you pass in.

The downside is of course that you need a lot more API calls. You would have to benchmark if the performance is better or worse than what you get with an extra copy.

Particularly for the `glTexImage2D()` case, another option might be to make the texture the size that matches the row length of your input data, and then only sample the part of the texture you want to use. You can do this by adjusting the range of texture coordinates during sampling.

Other than that, I can't think of a great way to do this in ES 2.0. Of course if you can constrain this to devices that support ES 3.0, moving to ES 3.0 is the obvious solution.